# Is it possible to disable body scrolling in PrettyPhoto lightbox?

Tags: prettyphoto

I don't know if anyone knows PrettyPhoto lightbox... I post this question here because project's forums seems to de dead.

Is there some way how to disable body scrolling when a photo is opened. The demo you can see here:
[demo](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto%5Bpp_gal%5D/1/)

If you scroll the page, the body is scrolling but opened lightbox stays in the same place. I want to disable body scrolling or to "attach" lightbox to the body so that it's scrolling together with the body.

Answer (score 1):

```
changepicturecallback: function(){
                $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});

            }, /* Called everytime an item is shown/changed */
            callback: function(){
                $('body').css({'overflow-y': 'visible'});

            }
```